# sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds sticks wrongly when the refresh control is showing

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

These images are from a collection view. The section header sticks to top perfectly unless the collection view is being refreshed. In that case the section header sticks down like it's being pushed down by the refresh control.

This is the code of creating the CollectionView

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
    layout.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true

    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height)
    collectionView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
    collectionView?.frame = frame
    collectionView?.setCollectionViewLayout(layout, animated: true)
    collectionView?.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    collectionView?.delegate = self
    collectionView?.dataSource = self
```

[image: First image]

[image: Second after scrolling down]

Comment: We need to see code

Comment: @BallpointBen I have added the code of creating the collectionView. if that what you want to see.